# Explain Matlab indexing/slicing in terms of Numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm converting some Matlab code into Python, and I've found a line I can not understand:

```
Y = reshape(X(j+(1:a*b),:),[b,a,p])
```

I know that the `reshape` function has a [numpy analog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and I have read the [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](https://la.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) document, but I can't seem to comprehend that line enough to convert it to `numpy` indexing/slicing.

I tried the [online converter OMPC](http://ompclib.appspot.com/m2py) but it uses [functions that are not defined outside of it](http://ompc.juricap.com/runing-maltab-r--scripts-in-pure-python) (like `mslice`):

```
Y = reshape(X(j + (mslice[1:a * b]), mslice[:]), mcat([b, a, p]))
```

I've also tried the [SMOP converter](https://github.com/victorlei/smop) but the result is also hard to understand:

```
Y = reshape(X(j + (arange(1, dot(a, b))), arange()), concat([b, a, p]))
```

Could you explain the conversion in simple Matlab to `numpy` indexing/slicing rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Y = X[j+np.arange(a*b),:].reshape((b,a,p))
```

Without knowing what you exactly want, this is a translation of the matlab line to python.

Notice that matlab indexes start at 1, while numpy's start at 0. So depending on the other lines the inner line could be either `np.arange(a*b)` or `np.arange(1,a*b)`.

Also you don't really need to use the second index of `X`, so `X[1,:]==X[1]` is `True`

Comment: Thank you @anishtain4! This particular portion of the Matlab code confuses me: `(1:a*b)`. Could you explain what this is doing?

Comment: See: [operator precedence](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html) and [`colon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)

Answer (score 1):

In an Octave session:

```
>> 1:3*3
ans =
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

In numpy ipython:

```
In [8]: np.arange(1,10)
Out[8]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [9]: np.arange(3*3)
Out[9]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: Thank you hpaulj. Yesterday I found that there's an online Octave compiler (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_octave_online.php) and it works great. I'm testing my code there now.